# Using Fit_XY in listview

Tags: java, android, android-listview

```
holder.item3.setImageResource(custom.getcustomImage());
```

This is a line of code in my custom `ListViewAdapter` that holds an imageview.  I need to get the images that i put in to shrink down to the size of my `ImageView` within the `ListView`.

I want to apply `imageview.setImageResource(custom.getcustomImage());` to the item in my adapter but i get an error.

```
Cannot invoke setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType) on the primitive type int
```

My code look like this

```
holder.item3.setImageResource(custom.getcustomImage().setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);
```

How am I suppose to use this `FIT_XY`, and is there another way I can fit an image the `ImageView` within my `ListView`?

My Adapter.

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Custom> {
        private ArrayList<Custom> entries;
        private Activity activity;

        public CustomAdapter(Activity a, int textViewResourceId,
                ArrayList<Custom> entries) {
            super(a, textViewResourceId, entries);
            this.entries = entries;
            this.activity = a;
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

        public class ViewHolder {
            public TextView item1;
            public TextView item2;
            public ImageView item3;

        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View v = convertView;
            ViewHolder holder;
            if (v == null) {
                LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) activity
                        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                v = vi.inflate(R.layout.rowlayout, null);
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.item1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.secondLine);
                holder.item2 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.firstLine);
                holder.item3 = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.icon);
                v.setTag(holder);
            } else
                holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();

            final Custom custom = entries.get(position);
            if (custom != null) {
                holder.item1.setText(custom.getcustomBig());
                holder.item2.setText(custom.getcustomSmall());
                holder.item3.setImageResource(custom.getcustomImage());
                holder.item3.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);
            }
            return v;
        }
    }
}
```

Line Calling code

```
a = new Custom("String one","Stringtwo", R.drawable.image);
```

Row Layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:padding="6dip" >

    <!-- android:background="@color/Cream" -->

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
        android:contentDescription="TODO"
        android:src="@drawable/launchicon" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/firstLine"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="26dip"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="Example application"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/secondLine"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/secondLine"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="Description"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that `item3` is an `ImageView`. You are trying to apply an image to that `ImageView`. 
Here, your `getcustomImage()` probably returns an imageResId.

If your getcustomImage() method returns an image res id(which is an integer value), use;

```
holder.item3.setImageResource(custom.getcustomImage());
```

to apply image to `ImageView`.

At the end there is no problem to use `setScaleType` on `ImageView`

```
holder.item3.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);
```

Read more about [setImageResource](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageResource%28int%29) and [setScaleType](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setScaleType%28android.widget.ImageView.ScaleType%29)

**Edit:** 
Shortly;
Change this;

```
holder.item3.setImageResource(custom.getcustomImage().setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);
```

With this:

```
holder.item3.setImageResource(custom.getcustomImage());
holder.item3.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);
```

**Edit:**
With saying wrap_content to your `ImageView` at your `rowlayout.xml` you are eliminating `scaleType` option because your `ImageView` is going to resize itself to your image's size. You may want to give a static width to get a better visual on your list(all images width will be equal). And you want fitXY but consider using centerinside as an option(to a better view). And try to use scaleOption at your rowlayout so you can see its output at graphical layout.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:padding="6dip" >

    <!-- android:background="@color/Cream" -->

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
        android:contentDescription="TODO"
        android:src="@drawable/launchicon" 
        android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/firstLine"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="26dip"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="Example application"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/secondLine"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/firstLine"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="Description"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I'm not getting an error, but my image does not fit the image view size.  I will post my adapter and the peice of code I am calling

Comment: I see your edit. Please share your rowlayout.Problem should be there.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I gave my imageviews a fixed value of 50dp and My images are re-sizing as it should.  Thank you for the other option types.  I've tried fitCenter but fitXY works well for me.